# BS4 Scraper is producing html of the entire div code, not just the href link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code for the website is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEIAa.png

The code I am using:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

sys.stdout = open("links.txt", "a")

for x in range(0, 2):
    try:
        URL = f'https://link.com/{x}'
        page = requests.get(URL)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        rows = soup.find_all('div', id='view')
        for row in rows:
            print(row.text)
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        continue
```

I just want an output of the list of links as shown in the highlighted code. But instead it results in the entire view code, not just the HREF, which is what I want.

Example of output that it produces:

```
<div id="view">
<a href="/watch/8f310ba6dfsdfsdfsdf" target="_blank"><img src="/thumbs/jpg/8f310ba6dfsdfsdfsdf.jpg" width="300"/></a>
...
...
```

When what I want it to produce is:

```
/watch/8f310ba6dfsdfsdfsdf
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code which will find all anchor tag under div tag and then get the `href` value.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for links in soup.find('div',id='view').find_all('a'):
    print(links['href'])
```

---

If you **Bs4 4.7.1** or above you can use following css selector.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for links in soup.select('#view>a'):
    print(links['href'])
```

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, if you have a lot of `a` tags inside `div` :)

Comment: I tried this and the output is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Aedam : If the data rendered by java scripts then BS4 doesn't help you to get the html you are after.BS4 works for static content not dynamic.

Comment: @KunduK just fixed it. I changed your soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser') back to my original         soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') but used the remainder of your code. Works perfect now!!

Answer (score 0):

By extracting the `href` attribute of the `a` inside the `div` you can get your desired result

```py
rows = soup.find_all('div', id='view')
for row in rows:
    links = row.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: The output is blank now?

Comment: Maybe because your HTML content has changed. Ensure that your request is returning valid HTML content as per your expectations for the BeautifulSoup parser

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the whole content of the `div` tag so if you want to get the links within the div then you need to add the `a` tag to the css seelctor as follows :

```
links = soup.select('div[id="view"] a')
for link in links :
    print(link.get('href'))
```